# Json filling dropdown with undefined

Tags: jquery, json

Json fills my Drop-down with undefined.

```
<option value="undefined">undefined</option>
<option value="undefined">undefined</option>
<option value="undefined">undefined</option>
etc
```

I use the follwing code to fill my Drop-Down;

```
$("select[name$='product_type']").change(function(){
    var url = "/all_json_models/" + $(this).val();
    var product_type = $(this).val();
    $.getJSON(url, function(products){
        var options = '<option value="Z">Select a type</option>';
        for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
            options += '<option value="' + products[i].pk + '">' + products[i].product_description + '</option>';
        }
        $("select#id_orderline_set-0-product").html(options);
        $("select#id_orderline_set-0-product option:first").attr('selected', 'selected');
        $("select#id_orderline_set-0-product").attr('disabled', false);
    });    
})
```

The contents of function(products);

```
[{
    "fields": {
        "timestamp_created": "2014-09-30T20:20:06.912Z",
        "timestamp_updated": "2014-09-30T20:20:06.912Z",
        "product_price": "102",
        "product_type": 6,
        "product_description": "Roef 95X25X6"
    },
    "model": "product.product",
    "pk": 9
},
{
    "fields": {
        "timestamp_created": "2014-10-23T19:27:37.570Z",
        "timestamp_updated": "2014-10-23T19:27:37.571Z",
        "product_price": "34",
        "product_type": 6,
        "product_description": "dfsfgsdfg"
    },
    "model": "product.product",
    "pk": 20
}]
```

What am I missing here so the Drop-Down uses the pk and product description?

when running `console.log(products[i]);` i get the following result in console;

```
[ ordercalculations.js:35
{ ordercalculations.js:35
" ordercalculations.js:35
f ordercalculations.js:35
i ordercalculations.js:35
e ordercalculations.js:35
l ordercalculations.js:35
d ordercalculations.js:35
s ordercalculations.js:35
" ordercalculations.js:35
etc
```

added my views.py

```
def all_json_models(request, id=None):
    if id:
        current_product_type = ProductType.objects.get(pk=id)
    else:
        current_product_type = ProductType()
    products = Product.objects.all().filter(product_type=current_product_type)
    products_serial = serializers.serialize("json", products)
    return HttpResponse(
                json.dumps(products_serial), content_type='application/json'
     )
```

Comment: debug through your code. do a `console.log` on your `product[i]` and see what you're getting. this would help you shed light on why the `pk` value is not accessible.

Comment: Wouldn't `product_description` be accessed as `products[i].fields.product_description`?

Comment: console.log = undefined

Comment: products[i].fields.product_description = Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'product_description' of undefined

Comment: obviously your `products` is not a object. try to create a blanc object first and than parse it

Comment: @phicon It just sucks when the solution is given first but a more recent and not quite correct one is selected as the answer :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$("select[name$='product_type']").change(function(){
    var url = "/all_json_models/" + $(this).val();
    var product_type = $(this).val();
    $.getJSON(url, function(products){
        products = $.parseJSON( products );
        var options = '<option value="Z">Select a type</option>';
        for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
            options += '<option value="' + products[i].fields.pk + '">' + products[i].fields.product_description + '</option>';
        }
        $("select#id_orderline_set-0-product").html(options);
        $("select#id_orderline_set-0-product option:first").attr('selected', 'selected');
        $("select#id_orderline_set-0-product").attr('disabled', false);
    });    
});
```

Comment: adding products = $.parseJSON( products ); did the trick! Many thanks!

Comment: no problem. your result was a string. you have to parse it first :)

Comment: @Dwza He wasn't accessing the property correctly, as `products[i].product_description` points to a property that doesn't exist. He needs `products[i]["fields"].product_description` to access the child within "fields."

Comment: @Growler if you view my source you will see i already saw this and fixed it. also `products[i]["fields"]` is wrong since parsing the json makes an object the correct access is `products[i].fields.XY`

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any obvious problem in your client code other than `products[i].fields.product_description` to get the product description.

The problem is that you are getting a string from the server so update your server to reply with a JSON object instead of a string.

If you can't, use `$.parseJSON()` to create an object from the `products` string.

About the server code: I am not familiar with Python but:
are you sure you need to serialize `products`?
is it `dumps()` or `dump()`?
try `mimetype` instead of `content_type`

Comment: I am not familiar with Python but are you sure you need to serialize `products`? Also is it `dumps` or `dump`? Also try `mimetype` instead of `content_type`

Comment: `console.log(typeof products);` after first loading, without doing `$.parseJSON( products );`, already shows products as an `object`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is: `products[i].product_description`

From your returned `json`: `product_description` is a child in the object "fields." You can tell this by console.logging the entire returned JSON object `products`

[image]

So you need to access that property by specifying "fields", as such:

`products[i]["fields"].product_description`

**Output:**

[image]

---

Here's my test:

**HTML:**

```
  <div id="test"></div>
    <select id="test2">

    </select>
```

**JS:**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
            var product_type = $(this).val();
            $.getJSON("./json/test.json", function(products){                       
                var options = '<option value="Z">Select a type</option>';
                for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
                    console.log(products);
                    options += '<option value="' + products[i].pk + '">' + products[i]["fields"].product_description + '</option>';
                }
                $("#test2").html(options);
            });    
        });
```

Comment: No, that wasn't his main problem.

Comment: @sebnukem how so? The values were coming back as `undefined` do to accessing properties incorrectly

Comment: There is no `product_description` or `fields` property on a string. See log in the post and the 4th comment.

Comment: @sebnukem `console.log(typeof products);` after first loading, without doing `$.parseJSON( products );`, already shows products as an `object`. Can you explain a bit? Mine worked fine, $.getJSON will already get it as an object