# Json filling my dynamically filled dropdown with undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, razor

I've been struggling with this for a day. and still cannot solve it and it should be something simple. I got 2 dropdowns, Country and City. When Country is selected i want to show the available cities for that country on the DB. but the dropdown fills with a big list of items with text **undefined**, the id is being returned correctly as I checked and the value is the correct id. Also i already looked at [Json filling dropdown with undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554408/json-filling-dropdown-with-undefined) but didn't seem to help, so here I leave my snippet of code to see if someone can spot what i cannot.

**HomeController.cs**

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
    {
        private XecuDateDevEntities db = new XecuDateDevEntities();
        List<SelectListItem> country = new List<SelectListItem>();
        List<SelectListItem> _city = new List<SelectListItem>();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            ViewBag.var1 = GetCountries();
            ViewBag.var2 = _city;
            return View();
        }

        private SelectList GetCountries()
        {

            foreach (Country c in db.Countries)
            {
                country.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = c.Country1, Value = c.IDCountry.ToString() });
            }
            return new SelectList(country, "Value", "Text", "id");

        }

        public JsonResult GetCities(string id)
        {
            foreach (City c in db.Cities.Where( x=> x.IDCountry.ToString() == id))
            {
                _city.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = c.City1, Value = c.IDCity.ToString() });
            } 
            return Json(_city, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
    }
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
<h2>Index</h2>
Country    @Html.DropDownList("var1", "Choose Country")
City       @Html.DropDownList("var2", "Choose City")
@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
            var id = $("#var1 :selected").val();
            var url = "Home/GetCities";
            var data1 = { "id": id };
            $.post(url, data1, function (data) {
                var items = [];
                items.push("<option value=" + 0 + ">" + "Choose City" + "</option>");
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                    items.push("<option value=" + data[i].Value + ">" + data[i].Text + "</option>");
                }
                $("#var2").html(items.join(' '));
            });
        }

        $("#var1").change(myFunction);


    </script>
}
```

Thanks!!!!

Comment: can you provide JSON data you are getting in `$.post` method ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach:

**Controller**:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{

        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            ViewBag.CountryList = new SelectList(_countryService.GetContries(), "Id", "Title");
            ViewBag.CityList = new SelectList(_cityService.GetaCities(), "Id", "Title");
            return View();
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public virtual JsonResult SelectCity(Guid id)
        {
            var cities = _cityService.GetaCities().Where(p => p.CountryId == id).Select(c => new { c.Id, c.Title });
            return Json(cities, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
}
```

**View**:

```
<div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CountryId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    <div>
                        @Html.DropDownList("CountryId", (SelectList)ViewBag.CountryList, "-- Select ---", new { @class = "form-control", id = "rdbCountry" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CityId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    <div>
                        @Html.DropDownList("CityId", (SelectList)ViewBag.CityList, "-- Select ---", new { @class = "form-control", id = "rdbCity" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CityId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
</div>


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('#rdbCountry').change(function () {
                    jQuery.getJSON('/Home/SelectCity/', { id: $(this).val() }, function (data) {
                        $('#rdbCity').empty();
                        jQuery.each(data, function (i) {
                            var option = $('<option></option>').attr("value", data[i].Id).text(data[i].Title);
                            $("#rdbCity").append(option);
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
    </script>
}
```